# OData Query Title startswith() A-M

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, csom

I am trying to query a list where the Title starts with a letter in the range from a to m and I can't find that anywhere in the sparse documentation available.

I tried this but it isn't valid and I am pretty sure that I would end up over the character limit allowed in a URL anyway.

```
/humanresources/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Corporate Directory')/items?$filter=( startswith(Title, 'a') Or startswith(Title, 'b')  )&?orderby=Title asc
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$filter=title ge 'a' and title lt 'n'
```

Comment: this answer is very cool!

Answer (score 5):

In your example there is a typo in [Filter expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248%28v=nav.71%29.aspx):

```
$filter=( startswith(Title, 'a') Or startswith(Title, 'b')  )
```

The name of logical operator is `or` (lowercase letters in name!) , please refer [Supported OData Query Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg312156.aspx) for a more details.

Below is provided a valid query:

```
/humanresources/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Corporate Directory')/items?$filter=startswith(Title, 'a') or startswith(Title, 'b')&?orderby=Title asc
```